# Как при помощи python скачать ЗАРАЖЁННЫЙ файл с гугл диска?

Tags: python

Добрай день!

Столкнулся с проблемой при скачивани с гугл диска с помощью Python. Файлы которые гугл отмечает как заражённые при скачивании повреждаются и их невозможно открыть. Что в этом случае можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение есть - скачать с дропбокса